# Issue with rest.nvim Plugin: JSON Formatting

Tags: curl, formatting, jq, neovim

I'm currently facing an issue with the rest.nvim plugin in Neovim. The plugin allows making HTTP requests within Neovim and provides a convenient way to format responses. I've configured it to use jq for formatting JSON responses, but it's not working as expected.
link to repo [rest-nvim/rest.nvim](https://github.com/rest-nvim/rest.nvim)

**Solution**
There was a breaking introduced to the plugin. A temporary fix here [here](https://github.com/rest-nvim/rest.nvim/issues/246%20Solution),

specify commit before breaking change in plugin config:

```
   return {
  {
    "rest-nvim/rest.nvim",
    requires = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" },
    -- latest commit breaks formatting
    commit = "8b62563",
    opts = {
      result_split_in_place = true,
    },
  },
}
```

**Problem:**
When I send an HTTP request using the rest.nvim plugin, the JSON responses are not being formatted correctly. Instead of getting a formatted JSON output, I receive the raw JSON response. I have jq installed on my system. Despite this, the formatting does not seem to take effect.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

1. Ensured jq is installed on my system.
2. Verified that the rest.nvim plugin is correctly installed and configured.
3. Checked the plugin's documentation and forums for similar issues, but couldn't find a solution.

**Example file:** *testing.http*

```
GET https://random-data-api.com/api/address/random_address
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response:**

```
GET https://random-data-api.com/api/address/random_address
#+END
#+RESPONSE
{"id":3318,"uid":"09951d24-0ba7-46e7-90c9-c75a1d1fa014","city":"Buckridgetown","street_name":"Eusebio Viaduct","street_address":"11676 Reatha Road","secondary_address":"Suite 204","building_number":"3557","mail_box":"PO Box 7129","community":"Willow Village","zip_code":"37775","zip":"42017-6516","postcode":"25460","time_zone":"America/St_Johns","street_suffix":"Park","city_suffix":"stad","city_prefix":"North","state":"Rhode Island","state_abbr":"WI","country":"United States Minor Outlying Islands","country_code":"PG","latitude":-74.28963865772323,"longitude":67.39583760610813,"full_address":"6652 Sanford Vista, South Trudichester, FL 91950-9038"}
#+END
```

**Configuration:**
Here's my current configuration for the rest.nvim plugin:

```
return {
    "rest-nvim/rest.nvim",
    requires = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" },
    config = function()
        require("rest-nvim").setup({

        -- Open request results in a horizontal split
        result_split_horizontal = false,
        -- Keep the http file buffer above|left when split horizontal|vertical
        result_split_in_place = false,
        -- Skip SSL verification, useful for unknown certificates
        skip_ssl_verification = false,
        -- Encode URL before making request
        encode_url = true,
        -- Highlight request on run
        highlight = {
            enabled = true,
            timeout = 150,
        },
        result = {
        -- toggle showing URL, HTTP info, headers at top the of result window
        show_url = true,
        -- show the generated curl command in case you want to launch
        -- the same request via the terminal (can be verbose)
        show_curl_command = false,
        show_http_info = true,
        show_headers = false,
        -- executables or functions for formatting response body [optional]
        -- set them to false if you want to disable them
            formatters = {
            json = "jq",
            html = function(body)
                return vim.fn.system({ "tidy", "-i", "-q", "-" }, body)
                end,
            },
        },
        -- Jump to request line on run
        jump_to_request = false,
        env_file = ".env",
        custom_dynamic_variables = {},
        yank_dry_run = true,
    })
        local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>rr", "<Plug>RestNvim", opts)
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>rp", "<Plug>RestNvimPreview", opts)
        vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>rl", "<Plug>RestNvimLast", opts)
    end,
}
```

Comment: If you have a solution to the problem/question, post an ANSWER. Do not edit the question to include the solution. Leave the question alone (with the real problem that exists) and write an appropriate answer which solves the problem of the question.